# Android LifeCycle - When Home and Back is Pressed

Tags: android

I have a quiz application project for our school. I want to prevent the users not to press the home and back button or leave the app, because if they do they will get 0 score.

We know about the lifecycle...

```
Start Application > onCreate > OnStart > OnResume > Activity Is running > OnFreeze > OnPause
```

If i pressed the home and back button, what method in the lifecycle will be invoked if I start the application again?

And in that method I will make a code to say the user has committed/cheat/left the application. Im thinking in the onResume?

Thanks.

Comment: there is no way in Android for the apps to intercept if Home key is pressed. Why? Well, this is done for security reasons. If it is allowed, any malicious app can override Both Back and Home key and then there is no way for the user to come out of the App, except rebooting the phone. So, there is no Defined API/callback for App to intercept Home Key. You need to use diff. hacks to Guess if Home is pressed....

Comment: If you target Android 5.0+, you can use the new Task Pinning API which allows you to put your app into a "kiosk mode" where the user cannot exit and will not be distracted by notifications.  Testing apps are one of the use cases specifically mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When back button pressed and exit the app

```
onPaused() -> onStop() -> onDestory()
```

When home button pressed

```
onPaused() -> onStop()
```

After pressed home button when again open app from recent task list or clicked on icon

```
onRestart() -> onStart() -> onResume()
```

Back button pressed from another app or settings then user can see our app

```
onRestart() -> onStart() -> onResume()
```

When open another app from notification bar or open settings

```
onPaused() -> onStop()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Activity** base class contains events that govern the `life cycle` of an activity.

**`onCreate():`** Called when the activity is first created

**`onStart():`** Called when the activity becomes visible to the user

**`onResume():`** Called when the activity starts interacting with the user

**`onPause():`** Called when the current activity is being paused and the previous activity is being resumed

**`onStop():`** Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user

**`onDestroy():`** Called before the activity is destroyed by the system

**`onRestart():`** Called when the activity has been stopped and is restarting again

> Example

```
public class LifeCycleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON CREATE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 
@Override
protected void onStart() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onStart(); 
    Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onResume(); 
    Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON RESUME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPause(); 
    Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON PAUSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onRestart(); 
    Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON RESTART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 
@Override
protected void onStop() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onStop(); 
    Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onDestroy(); 
    Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON DESTROY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
}
```

> Figure

[image: Android Life Cycle]

For more details visit [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/648480/Android-Activity-Life-Cycle)

and [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can find everything from here.